# Firefox OS: How can I turn on the flash of camera?

Tags: firefox-os, flashlight

i would like to keep the camera flash LED on.
is there any specific API?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible using the [mozCameras](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.mozCameras) API which you can use in Firefox OS 2.0 and higher.